# Individual bar colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, bar

I am trying to create a bar chart where all the bars are blue apart from one but, the last bar isn't being labeled. Below is my LaTeX code, any help would be appreciated.

https://www.overleaf.com/read/xczfctmnngvs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely, in your version also the blue bars are left of the ticks, and the orange one would be right of the tick if there is one. So you need to shift the bars in such a way that they are above the ticks. This can be done by introducing an absolute shift of `0mm`. (To see that this really does something, just comment these directives out and compare the results.) Then you can afford to add a fake blue bar and put an orange bar on top.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{\familydefault}
\usepackage[paperwidth=29.7cm,paperheight=42cm,left =1cm, top = 1cm, right =1cm, bottom = 1cm ,marginparwidth=0cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{times}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={font=\normalsize}} % size graph font
\graphicspath{{/aspfiles/latexReportImages/}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} %
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{181F50}
\definecolor{imagine}{HTML}{87cfeb}
\definecolor{lightblue}{HTML}{4f81c5}
\definecolor{oxfordblue}{HTML}{1f3057}
\definecolor{seagreen}{HTML}{96bf65}
\definecolor{olivegreen}{HTML}{4b5729}
\definecolor{lightbeige}{HTML}{f5e7a1}
\definecolor{goldenyellow}{HTML}{fcc808}
\definecolor{champagne}{HTML}{e6c18d}
\definecolor{salmonpink}{HTML}{f3b28b}
\definecolor{ruby}{HTML}{982d57}
\definecolor{lightorange}{HTML}{ffc299}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{bec0b8}
\definecolor{lightviolet}{HTML}{c9a8ce}
\definecolor{shellpink}{HTML}{fbded6}
\definecolor{mediumblue}{HTML}{0000CD}
\definecolor{lilac}{HTML}{c9a8ce}
\definecolor{saxo}{HTML}{1C5B92}
\definecolor{blue2}{HTML}{99c2ff}
\definecolor{lightgray2}{HTML}{d1d1e0}
\definecolor{redpink}{HTML}{ff9999}
\definecolor{lightyellow}{HTML}{ffffb3}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{HTML}{b3ffb3}
\definecolor{customcolor}{HTML}{00cc00}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\tikzstyle{chart}=[
legend label/.style={font={\Large},anchor=west,align=left},
legend box/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=10pt},
axis/.style={black,semithick,->},
axis label/.style={anchor=east,font={\tiny}}]
\newcommand{\pie}[5][]{
\begin{scope}[#1]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\curA}{90}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{#2}
\def\c{(0,0)}
\node[pie title] at (270:\r + 0.5) {#3};
\foreach \v/\s/\l/\x in{#4}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\deltaA}{\v/100*360}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nextA}{\curA + \deltaA}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\midA}{(\curA+\nextA)/2}
\path[slice,\s] \c
-- +(\curA:\r)
arc (\curA:\nextA:\r)
-- cycle;
\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
\path \c -- node[pos=\x,pie values,values of \s,font={#5}]{\l} +(\midA:\r);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\global\let\curA\nextA
}
\end{scope}
}
\newcommand{\legend}[2][]{
\begin{scope}[#1]
\path
\foreach \n/\s in {#2}{++(0,-10pt) node[\s,legend box] {} +(5pt,0) node[legend label] {\n}};
\end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{defaultCycle}{%
lightblue,ultra thick,sharp plot,mark=no\\%
orange,ultra thick,sharp plot,mark=no\\%
oxfordblue,ultra thick,sharp plot,mark=no\\%
lightgray2,ultra thick,sharp plot,mark=no\\%
lightorange,ultra thick,sharp plot,mark=no\\%
redpink,ultra thick,sharp plot,mark=no\\%
blue2,ultra thick,sharp plot,mark=no\\%
lightgreen,ultra thick,sharp plot,mark=no\\%
purple,ultra thick,sharp plot,mark=no\\%
olivegreen,ultra thick,sharp plot,mark=no\\%
champagne,ultra thick,sharp plot,mark=no\\%
lilac,ultra thick,sharp plot,mark=no\\%
lightyellow,ultra thick,sharp plot,mark=no\\%
}


\flushleft
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    cycle list name=defaultCycle,
    width=0.5\linewidth,
    height=0.2\textheight,
    symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e},
    xtick=data,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/1000 sep},
    scaled y ticks=false,
    xtick pos=left,
            legend style={draw=none,at={(0,1.03)},anchor=south west},
    legend columns=-1,
    yticklabel style={rotate=0},,
    bar width=20pt,             % reduced bar width for overlapping,
    x tick label style ={font=\normalsize,text width=2cm,align=center,anchor=north},
    ymajorgrids,
    ybar,
    %xtickmin=a, xtickmax=e,
    ytick pos=left,
    xlabel=\textbf{},
    ylabel=\textbf{},
    title={\textbf{}}
    ]
        \addplot[ybar,fill=lightblue,mark=no,bar shift=0mm] coordinates {
         (a,3.5)
         (b,-0.75)
         (c,-4.85)
         (d,-3.33)
         (e,0)
        };
        \addplot[ybar,fill=orange,mark=no,bar shift=0mm] coordinates {
         (e,7)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! does bar shift =0pt reduce the gap between bars?

Comment: @SimranJ I do not think so. Note, however, that in your original setting the bars were drawn as if there were two sets of data, and, accordingly, two sets of bars next to each other. Why do you ask?